# ¿Cómo configurar Unbound como servidor DNS de manera local?

Tags: dns

Necesito un servidor DNS de manera local y no quiero instalar Windows server. Encontré que existe esta herramienta "Unbound" que hace la función de servidor DNS, pero no sé configurarla para que me resuelva los nombres de dominio que me hacen falta. Alguien sabe cómo configurarla?
Saludos y gracias.

Pongo aquí la solución que encontré porque no cabe en un comentario. Disculpen las molestias.

Use esta configuración y funcionó.

```
# Unbound configuration file on windows.
# See example.conf for more settings and syntax
server:
# verbosity level 0-4 of logging
verbosity: 0

#For query in all interface
interface: 0.0.0.0

# if you want to log to a file use
#logfile: "C:\unbound.log"

# on Windows, this setting makes reports go into the Application log
# found in ControlPanels - System tasks - Logs
#use-syslog: yes

#Change the path for x86 OS
server: auto-trust-anchor-file: "C:\Program Files\Unbound\root.key"

port: 53
do-ip4: yes
do-ip6: no
do-udp: yes
do-tcp: yes
prefetch: yes
prefetch-key: yes
hide-identity: yes
hide-version: yes
harden-glue: yes
harden-dnssec-stripped: yes
outgoing-range: 512
num-queries-per-thread: 1024
num-threads: 2
msg-cache-size: 128m
rrset-cache-size: 256m
msg-cache-slabs: 8
rrset-cache-slabs: 8
infra-cache-slabs: 8
key-cache-slabs: 8
key-cache-size: 16m
so-rcvbuf: 1m
so-sndbuf: 1m
cache-min-ttl: 3600
cache-max-ttl: 172800
infra-host-ttl: 60
infra-lame-ttl: 120
unwanted-reply-threshold: 10000
infra-cache-numhosts: 10000
infra-cache-lame-size: 10k
val-clean-additional: yes
minimal-responses: yes

### Block popular advertising companies
#Redirection zone
local-zone: "doubleclick.net" redirect
local-data: "doubleclick.net A 127.0.0.1"
local-zone: "googlesyndication.com" redirect
local-data: "googlesyndication.com A 127.0.0.1"
local-zone: "googleadservices.com" redirect
local-data: "googleadservices.com A 127.0.0.1"
local-zone: "google-analytics.com" redirect
local-data: "google-analytics.com A 127.0.0.1"
local-zone: "ads.youtube.com" redirect
local-data: "ads.youtube.com A 127.0.0.1"
local-zone: "adserver.yahoo.com" redirect
local-data: "adserver.yahoo.com A 127.0.0.1"
```

Lo que en un momento determinado dió error cuando compartía la red por WIFI mediante el connectify.